# Comparando dos arrays en Java

Tags: java, array, string

Estoy haciendo este ejercicio en el que tengo dos arreglos, tengo que contar cuantas cambios tengo que realizar para llegar de uno a otro. Por ejemplo: arregloUno = ["123"] , arregloDos =  ["321"]

Tengo que comparar cada digito de las cadenas de ambos arreglos. Comparo del arreglo1 el 1 con el arreglo2 3 y tengo que contar cuantas veces tengo que modificar el 1 para llegar al tres serian 2 veces. Y así con todos el 2 con el 2 son iguales entonces ahí
no cuento y el 3 y el 1 son otras dos veces, entonces en total serian 4 cambios los que tengo que realizar.
Hasta ahora tengo esto...

```
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese el limite para los vectores: ");
        int limite = teclado.nextInt();

        String[] arregloUno = new String[limite];
        String[] arregloDos = new String[limite];

        int contador = 0;
        boolean retorno = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < arregloUno.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese los caracteres para el primer arreglo:");
            arregloUno[i] = teclado.nextLine();

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arregloUno.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese los caracteres para el segundo arreglo:");
            arregloDos[i] = teclado.nextLine();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arregloUno.length; i++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < arregloDos.length; x++) {
                if (arregloUno[i].charAt(i) == arregloDos[x].charAt(i)) {

                    retorno = true;

                } else if (arregloUno[i] != arregloDos[x]) {

                    contador = contador + 1;
                    retorno = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (retorno == true) {
            System.out.print("la palabra fue encontrada");
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar más ejemplos del input/output que esperarías?

La redacción es algo confusa, ¿Necesitas contar cuántos lugares separan el primer dígito del primero arreglo con su coincidencia en el segundo?, si es así, tal vez te sirva el método [indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-)

Comment: Exactamente @Eduardo Jiménez. Ej: como input tengo array1["12"] , array2["32"] y tengo que ir comparándolos...
    array1[0] =1 con array2[0] =3 para llegar de array1 al array2 necesitaría hacer 2 
    cambios, lo acumulo en una variable contador=2
    array1[1] =2 con array2[1] =2 para llegar de array1 al array2 no necesito hacer 
    cambios son iguales
    Entonces como output obtendría el resultado de contador que seria 2.

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo muy bien la salida que deseas

Lo que si he visto, es que tienes varios errores en tu código

Aquí, te pongo un código corregido que muestra las veces que coinciden y no coinciden los caracteres de cada array

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingrese el limite para los vectores: ");
    int limite = teclado.nextInt();
    //vaciamos el búfer del teclado, lo hay que hacer después de introducir un número y esperar luego un carácter no numérico
    teclado.nextLine();

    String[] arregloUno = new String[limite];
    String[] arregloDos = new String[limite];

    //declaramos dos variables de enteros para coincidencias o no coincidencias
    int contadorSI = 0, contadorNO = 0;

    //pedimos los caracteres del primer array, para que no se repita siempre el mismo texto, lo sacamos del bucle
    System.out.println("Ingrese los caracteres para el primer arreglo:");
    for (int i = 0; i < arregloUno.length; i++) {
        //vamos pidiendo los caracteres indicando cardinalidad
        System.out.println("Introduzca carácter " + (i + 1) + " de " + arregloUno.length);
        //agegamos el carácter al array
        arregloUno[i] = teclado.nextLine();
    }
    //marcamos final del primer array
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");

    //pedimos caracteres del segundo array
    System.out.println("Ingrese los caracteres para el segundo arreglo:");
    for (int i = 0; i < arregloDos.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Introduzca carácter " + (i + 1) + " de " + arregloDos.length);
        arregloDos[i] = teclado.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");

    //los bucles para comparar el contenido de los array
    for (int i = 0; i < arregloUno.length; i++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < arregloDos.length; x++) {
            //utilizamos equals e ignoramos si están en mayúscula o minúscula. Si deseamos que haya esa diferencia, eliminamos IgnoreCase
            if (arregloUno[i].equalsIgnoreCase(arregloDos[x])) {
                //si coincide algún carácter, aumentamos en uno la variable
                contadorSI++;
            } else {
                //si no coincide el carácter aumentamos uno la variable
                contadorNO++;
            }
        }
    }
    //imprimimos el resultado de los contadores
    System.out.println("Coinciden: " + contadorSI);
    System.out.println("No Coinciden: " + contadorNO);
}
```

Comment: Te agradezco mucho las correcciones @el.trasgu, me ayudan mucho para seguir aprendiendo. El ejercicio lo que me pide es comparar dos arreglos
Ej: tengo array1["12"] , array2["32"] y tengo que ir comparándolos.
    array1[0] =1 con array2[0] =3 para llegar de array1 al array2 necesitaría hacer 2 
    cambios, lo acumulo en una variable contador=2
    array1[1] =2 con array2[1] =2 para llegar de array1 al array2  no necesito hacer 
    cambios son iguales
    Entonces como salida obtendría el resultado de contador que seria 2.

Comment: Lo que no entiendo entonces es que si tienes que comparar array de enteros, porque has declarado los array como string y luego pides caracteres para dar valores a los array en lugar de números.

Comment: Lo puse como ejemplo serian cadenas de numeros, pero lo que tengo que comparar son 2 array de string.